# How to auto extent the height of a father with a absolute positioned child?

Tags: css

```
<head>
<style type = "text/css">
body{
text-align:center;
}

#container{
position:relative;
width:600px;
height:auto;
border:1px solid #ccbbaa;
}

#box{
position:absolute;
width:300px;
left:2px;
border:1px solid #ccbbaa;
}


</style>
</head>
<div id = "container">

<div id = "box">
<p>
message .....
</p>
<p>
message .....
</p>
</div>
    </div>
```

The question is how to make the height of container and box consistent using not fixed height.

thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `consistent`? Do you want the bottom of the `box` to touch the bottom of `container`?

Comment: Yes, I mean `same` by `consistent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you use javascript? Here is my way by using jQuery:

```
$("#box").resize(function() {
  $("#container").width($(this).width()).height($(this).height());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the child `box` div, relatively positioned. Absolutely positioned `box` will not make the container auto extend height.

Comment: but I have to make the child box div absolute positioned.thanks

Comment: @guy, then JavaScript is your only choice. Like @PeterWong answered.